# undefined method `session_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I am using Rails + Devise + OmniAuth + Google OAuth2.

My user model (user.rb) contains:

```
devise :registerable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]
```

My routes.rb look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
  devise_scope :user do
      get 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
      post 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/session#create', :as => :user_session
      get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  get 'services', to: 'static_pages#services'
  get 'my_account', to: 'my_account#index'
  get 'invite', to: 'invite#show'
  get 'invite/:id', to: 'invite#show'

  root 'static_pages#home'
end
```

When I go to /sign_in, I get an exception like:

```
undefined method `session_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9b7173af28>:0x007f9b713d8da8>
```

in:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
```

in line:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

If I add :database_authenticatable to user.rb it all starts working, but I want my users to be able to sign-in through Google OAuth2 only, so I don't want :database_authenticable. It looks like session_path is not available for some reason, but I am not sure why and how to make it available.

Thanks,
Jen

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am not using OmniAuth either Google OAuth2. Did you solve it at the end?

Answer (score 82):

You need to reboot the rails server. That was the solution for me.

Comment: Yes.  I added a registrations_controller.rb file and forgot to reboot.  Lesson: the file structure is like an initializer in development mode.

Comment: Useful answer. Saved more time than Geico saves on insurance.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that, as you use `devise_scope` for the `sessions` paths, you need to add `skip` to your `devise_for` call, like so:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions], controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
```

Doing so will not generate the route helpers for the `sessions` controller

Answer (score 0):

If you add or modify anything in the devise configuration, you need to reboot the rails server. just stop and run the `rails server` command again